# Quando não encontrar arquivo, deve passar para o próximo step (Spring Batch)

Tags: java, spring

Estou usando Spring Batch.

No meu Job, tenho vários step's, e todos eles leem de um arquivo .csv.

O problema é o seguinte, haverá momentos em que o arquivo .csv não estará no local disponível para leitura. Quando isso acontece, estoura um erro e o Job para, porém eu gostaria que simplesmente ele fosse para o próximo step.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pesquise sobre SkipPolicy.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

Na classe `FlatFileItemReader`, é só chamar o método `setStrict(false)`;

Por default este valor é true. Quando o valor é true e o arquivo não é encontrado, ele laça um erro e termina o Step com `BatchStatus.FAILED`.

Se o valor é false, quando ocorre um erro, ele simplesmente termina o Step como `BatchStatus.COMPLETED`.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é usar a tag de decisão. Por exemplo:

```
<batch:decision id="decision" decider="decider">
    <batch:next on="FULL" to="fullStep" />
    <batch:next on="FAILED" to="nextStep" />
</batch:decision>
```

Ou, como voce pode ver na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/index-single.html#programmaticFlowDecisions).

```
public class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        String status;
        if (someCondition()) {
            status = "FAILED";
        }
        else {
            status = "COMPLETED";
        }
        return new FlowExecutionStatus(status);
    }
}
```